# LibreCalc Conditionally Display Word

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

How to display the word PASSED in cell H5 if the grade under H5 is equal to or greater than the number in cell C12?

Comment: Some diagrams or screen shots of your data would help us understand your question. Please [edit] your question to include some example (mock) data (before and after). See [Format Text as a Table](http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html) for a web utility that will help you to create a nice data table you can paste into your question. Upload any image(s) to [Imgur](http://www.imgur.com) and you will get link(s) you can share. [Edit] your question to include the link(s) and someone with sufficient reputation will inline the image(s) for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the grade is in H6, then put this in H5:

```
=IF(H6>=C12,"PASSED","FAILED")
```